# how to handle large array dataset in mongo map reduce function

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I have a map/reduce job that builds up an array where the reduce
performs array concatenation. Sometimes the resulting document seems
to hit the max bson size limit and map reduce fails with "value too large to reduce" error.

please let us know how to handle this situation. i want all the documents in the array. i cannot concatenate in the array since its failing with above error if there are more documents..

Thanks
MRK

Comment: afaik there's currently no way around it except source modification. you probably need to rethink the way you do the reduction.

Answer (score 3):

You could use something like the MongoDB Hadoop Adapter to run your map reduce job on a real map/reduce framework.

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/